# Angular: How to properly find and add class to angular element based on validators

Tags: angular

I have prepared a directive that should be set on each formControl that is checking if given formControl contains a required validator. More or less based on this: [Angular FormControl check if required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557690/angular-formcontrol-check-if-required) but wrapped into directive.

Now I am stuck on problem of finding closest label element to add special class to it.
I started with getting this.el.nativeElement.previousSibling and appending class via renderer2 but then I noticed that not every input in my app is the same and I have 2 cases possible:

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <input directive></input>
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <div>
    <input directive></input>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to get closest label to my input? Tried using webAPI's closest function but it seems not working and returning null unless I am calling it on wrong object (tried both - this.el and this.el.nativeElement).

Or is my apprach totally wrong and it should be done somehow else?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this? I do believe there are other solutions.

Comment: Basically I want to mark all required fields by making the labels of required fields bolder than non required ones. Also while at this I wanted to refresh my memory about directives and DOM manipulation

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be adding an `ngClass` attribute to your label whenever the control has an error (or even a particular one).

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label [ngClass]="{ 'field-error': form.controls.myinput.errors }">
  <input formControlName="myinput">
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
based on your requirements you can check for `required` errors in your form control

```
<label [ngClass]="{ 'field-error': form.controls.myinput.errors?.required }">
```

EDIT2:

```
<label [ngClass]="{ 'field-required': hasRequiredValidator(form.controls.myinput) }">

and in your component:
hasRequiredValidator(control => /* return true if control has Validators.required */);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but this will work only when the field contains an error. I want to mark fields (making the label bolder) that are required. No matter if it is already filled (no error) or still empty

Comment: the error attribute is available since the form is instantiated and you should see the class applied as soon as you load the page. Try it