# How to pass values to children component Anguar?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with children inside:

```
 <app-documents-mode-register [id_files]="getCheckedCheckboxesValues('id_file')"></app-documents-mode-register>
```

Where method `getCheckedCheckboxesValues` is:

```
public getCheckedCheckboxesValues(property: string): number[] {
    return this.checkboxes
        .toArray()
        .slice(1)
        .filter((element: any) => element.value)
        .map((element) => element.application[property]);
}
```

So I try to pass `[id_files]` to children component, but I have read that not recommended way to pass function as Input parameter. How to improve it?

The `app-documents-mode-register` component has `onPush`

Comment: Will the resulting array change? For what you have read you can also rad here for example: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: Yes, resulting array will be changed

Comment: I think it will be better if you use a pipe instead of a function.

Comment: How? I just need pass array of numbers each time

Comment: 1. Create a variable in the parent. 2. Set the variable using the parent method that you have. 3. Control the change detection from that variable in the child through ngOnChanges

Comment: Is it good solution? post please an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the pipe like this.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'checkedValues' })
export class CheckedValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(checkboxes: any, property: string): number[] {
    return checkboxes.toArray().slice(1).filter((element: any) => 
  element.value).map((element) => element.application[property]);
  }
}
```

And use the pipe in the template.

```
<app-documents-mode-register [id_files]="checkboxes | checkedValues : 'id_file'"></app-documents-mode-register>
```

Please make sure that the `checkboxes` is a public member in the component class.

Comment: What is benefit of using pipe? Whats is difference from my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332039/methods-vs-pipes
Here is the best answer for your question. The pipe is called only when the input value changed but the methods are called on every change detection.

Comment: Why you dont use `[id_files]`?

Comment: It does not worl for me

Comment: Inside `DocumentsModeRegister` I have  `@Input() id_files: number[] = [];` So, values is not passed to children component using pipe

Comment: I've just updated my answer a little. Please check again.
`[id_files]="checkboxes | checkedValues : 'id_file'"`

Comment: I dont know why but your solutions not pushed a new array to children

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224734/angular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224735/discussion-between-triaton-and-jony).