# Angular *ngIf Condition inside *ngFor to show hide items

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am working with angular 12. Here is the angular html code.

```html
    <ul id="respMenu" class="horizontal-menu">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let i = index">
                 <ng-container *ngIf="IsAllowed(['admin','user'])">
                 <li>
                     <a>
                         <span class="title">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
             </ng-container>
             </ng-container>
         </ul>
```

i am calling this method show hide my li

```
  IsAllowed(allowedRoles){
    console.log("test");
    for (var i = 0; i < userRoles.length; i++) {
        if(allowedRoles.includes(userRoles[i])){
           return true;
        }
    }
  }
```

[image]

But it console the test text like thousands of times. why is this so please suggest me better way to do it.I Have 8 menuItems its shows 8 in UI but console many times.

IsAllowed Method parameter will be loaded dynamically and will be different for every item.

Comment: How many menuItems do you have?

Comment: i have 8 menuItems

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081810/angular2-infinite-loop-when-i-call-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-templa

Comment: What are you expecting in IsAllowed() method. can you share actual code of that method?

Comment: i wanted to add some condition like if it's admin return true else false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Abhishek Priyadarshi already wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68441470/6537157) ...

The problem is the change-detection of angular. It will call your method again and again, ... to check if the value changed.
One way to solve it, is to change the change-detection. `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is the best option, but this may break your component. Please read the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy).

And here is the reason, why I wrote a new answer: You should write a new structural directive. So you can use the method on all components and have a "standard". Have a look to the [strucural directive docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives).

Here is a idea how your code can be look like:

#### HTML:

```html
<ng-container *appAllowed="user,admin">
    <li>
        <a>
            <span class="title">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

#### TS

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appAllowed]'})
export class AllowedDirective {

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set appAllowed(allowed: string) {
    var allowedList = allowed.split(',');

    for (let requiredRole of allowedList) {
       if (!this.userService.hasRole(required)) {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
          return;
       }
    }
    
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

If you can't use the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, then you can reduce the workload, like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appAllowed]'})
export class AllowedDirective {

  private roles: string[];

  constructor(userService: UserService,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
      userService.me().subscribe(me => this.roles = me.roles);
  }

  @Input() set appAllowed(allowed: string) {
    var allowedList = allowed.split(',');

    for (let requiredRole of allowedList) {
       if (!this.roles.includes(requiredrole)) {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
          return;
       }
    }
    
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. works like a champ and make it more easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite this as a pipe. Pipes are executed when a value changes, functions are executed every time change detection is run. More details can be found in this [Stackoverflow question and answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332039/methods-vs-pipes)

Comment: how can i do it in my case i need to add some conditions in IsAllowed() Method.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you need to check first if user logged in is admin or not and for that in your component :

```
get isAdmin(): boolean {
   if(this.user == 'admin') {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then in your HTML component :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isAdmin">
     <li>
         <a>
            <span class="title">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
         </a>
     </li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: i have added some more information to question.

Comment: So function has nothing to do with menuItem so you can create two seprate variables in your .ts like isAdmin and isUser and return true/false for them using function in your component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **TrackBy** Function inside the ngFor loop.

On each ngDoCheck triggered for the ngForOf directive, Angular checks what objects have changed. It uses differs for this process and each differ uses the trackBy function to compare the current object with the new one. The default trackBy function tracks items by identity:

```
const trackByIdentity = (index: number, item: any) => item;
```

Example of `trackBy` inside `*ngFor`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let i = index; trackBy:trackByIdentity;">
```

How `trackByIdentity` funtion looks like on your controller

```
trackByIdentity(menuItem) {
    return menuItem.title; // here, you can track by any field.
}
```

If you're curious how ngFor works under the hood, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108217/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor).

Answer (score 0):

You can use change detection strategy in component

```
@Component({
  // ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the logic of IsAllowed() Method?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if I understood your question. It checks the users roles until it finds one that is allowed. If none found, returns false.

```
  IsAllowed(allowedRoles){
    userRoles.forEach(role => {
       if (allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
          return true
       }
    }
    return false
  }
```

Comment: it works already fine but loop never stops even if i return false of true hardcoded.